# Configure Active Directory with desktop application

Tags: c#, winforms, active-directory

I am working on a desktop application that needs to configure user authentication and authorization with the AD. I am developing this application as Windows Form Application.

I faced following issues and I am looking for the right direction.

1. In my research, I saw that there is no session state like in web application. So once I configure the AD with desktop, How to manage the user token that provides by AD?
2. Once the user closes the application without log out, when the next time that user should be able to open the application without login. So what is the approach to achieve that?

Comment: 1) what user token is provided by AD? Are you talking about Kerberos ticket?
2) That is possible if your users are running the app on the computers from the same domain. Otherwise, you would have to just store some local state somewhere with user identity, although that would be insecure.

Comment: When a user logs in, you create an ad connection and maintain it until your program is closed. Credentials will not be cached, until windows password manager is not involved. Not sure if this manager has api, but you can encrypt credentials and store them in lsa. However this s not secure